# Increase/decrease a percentage in prices with same identifier

Tags: excel

I have one sheet that have tree columns: name|price|brand

But I need to increase or decrease the price in the range that have the same brand:

```
name1|10.00|brand1 <- increase 10%
name1|15.35|brand1 <- increase 10%
name1|4.15|brand1 <- increase 10%
name1|5.18|brand2 <- increase 15%
name1|8.65|brand2 <- increase 15%
name1|7.77|brand2 <- increase 15%
name1|5.18|brand3 <- decrease 4%
name1|8.65|brand3 <- decrease 4%
name1|7.77|brand3 <- decrease 4%
```

How I do this easy and fast without I need to change the lines one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest setting up a small lookup table containing your brands and the percentage change, thus:

```
brand1 | 10%
brand2 | 15%
brand3 | -4%
```

You can then use a `VLOOKUP` formula next to each data point to find the brand and return the percentage change. Incorporate that into your calculation. Assuming that your data starts in A1, and your lookup table starts in F1, your formula would look something like this:

```
=B1+(B1*VLOOKUP(C1,$F$1:$G$3,2,False))
```

You should get something like this:

[image: Sample]

The beauty of this method is that you can make your list of brands as long as you need without having to extensively rewrite every time.

Once you have your formula column, you can use Copy/Paste Special (Values) to paste the results over the top of the existing values if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**For LibreOffice**

Since it seems your data is sorted by brand and unlikely you will need to repeat the above often (with the percentages as the example) an alternative that might be easier is to enter `1.1`, `1.15` and `.96` in a header row then filter by brand in turn, copy one of the factors (eg `1.1` for `brand1`) then select the visible values and Paste Special with Selection Numbers (only) and Operations Multiply (only) - then repeat for the other brands.

Would not be practical if for very many brands and though it might be convenient not to have a separate column for 'new' prices (if say the previous column is referenced elsewhere) it would mean the loss of the price history (if a copy is not taken first).